# Can't archive Hbase compacted file because of isCompactedAway=true or file has reference

Tags: hbase

On one of the region servers in my Hbase cluster, I am observing a gradual increase in heap size (increase in old gen). This leads to old gen GC running, leading to stalling of Hbase process, which leads to higher latencies.

**Heap Size Graph (max heap size = 24gb)**
[image]

I am also seeing the following exceptions in the region server logs:

> 2022-09-27 00:25:49,839 INFO [RS_COMPACTED_FILES_DISCHARGER-regionserver/hbase-rs-1:16020-1] regionserver.HStore: Can’t archive compacted file hdfs://{root-dir}/apps/hbase/data/data/default/{table-name}/f036c427f61a3b4150978345f015d840/c/ffa9b24669a3402fb783398c89122896 because of either isCompactedAway=true or file has reference, isReferencedInReads=true, refCount=280, skipping for now.

Looks like the references to the compacted files are not getting freed up, thereby adding to the ever growing heap size. Because of this, these files are not getting archived too.
I tried restarting the Region Server to free up the references to the compacted files. This provided a temporary solution, but heap size started increasing again after two days.

*hbase.master.hfilecleaner.ttl* config is set to its default of 5 minutes.

I have a cluster of 15 Region Servers, all of which are running fine, except this particular region server. Looking for a proper solution here thats helps me in managing the heap size properly.

**Hbase version:** 2.1.7

Answer (score 0):

The number of storefiles being retained would not cause heap size exhaustion. That will simply cause your storage usage to increase. However, the problem seems related and `isReferencedInReads=true` is the hint.

It seems that you (or your clients) are running scan operations on this cluster without closing them. If a scan operation is left alive; it will not only prevent cleanup of store files but will also keep taking memory on the region server for tracking those scan operations.

Check out [ResultScanner#close](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/ResultScanner.html#close--) on how to close a scanner.
Also check out `hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period` setting on automatically expiring leases for scanners that are not being closed.